# If checked then disabled form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form

I have these code:

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.input :start_work, as: :date, start_year: Date.today.year - 20,
                                            end_year: Date.today.year, ignore_day: true,
                                            order: [:month, :year],
                                            input_html: { class: 'form-control' },
                                            label: 'Start work period' %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.input :is_current, label: 'Currently work here', input_html: { class: 'current' } %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.input :end_work, input_html: {class: 'end_work'}, as: :date, start_year: Date.today.year - 20,
                                            end_year: Date.today.year, ignore_day: true,
                                            order: [:month, :year],
                                            input_html: { class: 'form-control' },
                                            label: 'End work period' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // experience current work
    $(".current").each(function() {
      $(this).click(function() {
        var isCurrent = $(this).prop("checked");
        if (isCurrent == true) {
          $(this).closest('.form-group').next('.form-group').find('.end_work').prop("disabled", "disabled");
        }
        else {
          $(this).closest('.form-group').next('.form-group').find('.end_work').prop("disabled", false);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

However, I can't disabled my end_work input when the current box checked. I think I missed the target class or something on Javascript. Any helps will be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(this).closest('.form-group').next('.form-group')` doesn't do what you think it does. The `div.form-group`s aren't siblings in the DOM so, if I'm not mistaken, `.next('.form-group')` won't be able to find anything.

Try `$(this).closest('.col-sm-4').next('.col-sm-4').find('.end_work')`.

---

Incidentally, this code is redundant:

```
$(".current").each(function() {
  $(this).click(function() {
    ...
```

... because `.click` already attachs a click handler to every element matched by the selector. You can accomplish the same thing with just one line:

```
$(".current").click(function() {
  ...
```